# Updating URL from TabBar selection

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I'm currently working on updating a Flutter Web app to support sharing pages via URLs. I currently have a screen that uses a `TabBar`, and shows different views based on the selected tab. I want to be able to do two things:

- Update the URL when a tab is selected (e.g. append `&section=tabName` to the URL)
- Paste the URL into a new browser tab and have the application open on the tab specified by the URL

The second part of this was simple enough, just take the `&section=...` argument and use that to set the `initialIndex` of the tab controller. Updating the URL however seems quite difficult.

I've tried using `RouteInformationParser` to generate a new route from a list of arguments, but that triggers the `onGenerateRoute` callback and just seems to re-navigate to the page with the `initialIndex` updated from the new URL. I can get around this by replacing the `TabBarView` with a nested Navigator that navigates to the selected tab's content, but it seems like this could quickly become quite clunky if you wanted to navigate deeper than just a selected tab.

A simpler option I've seen mentioned is `window.history.replaceState`, which seems a lot simpler but feels like a bit of a kludge. Are there any ways of doing this that I've missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hacky, but I was able to force a URL change on tabbed navigation by using the TabBar.onTap, which provides the tab index, and having navigation happen through that. It ruined the nice slide action, but I got the custom URL in the address bar, which was more important for my use.